# insert variable output of script in multiple lines using sed

Tags: variables, sed, insert

test file contains

```
$ cat test
i-d119c118,vol-37905322,,,2015-07-29T03:50:32.511Z,General Purpose SSD,15
i-2278b42e,vol-c90539cc,,,2014-11-12T04:27:22.618Z,General Purpose SSD,10
```

script output:

```
$ for instance_id in $(cut -d"," -f1 test); do python getattrib.py get $instance_id | cut -d"'" -f2; done
10.10.0.68
10.10.0.96
```

inserting variable using sed yields following result, note the same IP address

```
$ insert=( `for instance_id in $(cut -d"," -f1 test); do python getattrib.py get $instance_id | cut -d"'" -f2; done` )
$ sed "s|$|,${insert}|" test
i-d119c118,vol-37905322,,,2015-07-29T03:50:32.511Z,General Purpose SSD,15,10.10.0.68
i-2278b42e,vol-c90539cc,,,2014-11-12T04:27:22.618Z,General Purpose SSD,10,10.10.0.68
```

but i am looking for output as below:

```
10.10.0.68,i-d119c118,vol-37905322,,,2015-07-29T03:50:32.511Z,General Purpose SSD,15
10.10.0.96,i-2278b42e,vol-c90539cc,,,2014-11-12T04:27:22.618Z,General Purpose SSD,10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use start delimiter `^` instead of end `$` and adapt the `,`

```
sed "s/^/${insert},/" test
```

but your sed and value retreiving need to be into the loop, not after or taking all result as value

example in loop:

```
for instance_id in $(cut -d"," -f1 test)
 do
   insert="$( python getattrib.py get ${instance_id} | cut -d"'" -f2 )"
   sed -e "/^${instance_id}/ !d" -e "s|$|,${insert}|" test
 done
```

Comment: thanks @NeronLeVelu. that solved the issue of printing in the first column. how do i put sed and value retrieving in a loop?

Comment: thanks @NeronLeVelu. We're nearly there but not quite.. The first $insert is appended to both lines then the second $insert is appended to both lines.. The output is as below:-

`10.10.0.68,i-d119c118,vol-37905322,,,2015-07-29T03:50:32.511Z,General Purpose SSD,15
10.10.0.68,i-2278b42e,vol-c90539cc,,,2014-11-12T04:27:22.618Z,General Purpose SSD,10
10.10.0.96,i-d119c118,vol-37905322,,,2015-07-29T03:50:32.511Z,General Purpose SSD,15
10.10.0.96,i-2278b42e,vol-c90539cc,,,2014-11-12T04:27:22.618Z,General Purpose SSD,10`

Comment: you are right, forget to filter insed while in loop., added to the sed command.

Comment: Thank you @NeronLeVelu.. But the `/ !d` needs to be `/! d`. It is working now.

Comment: normaly the space is after the adress, with the command but if it works for you, it's fine

Answer (score 0):

```
insert=( `for instance_id in $(cut -d"," -f1 test); do python getattrib.py get $instance_id | cut -d"'" -f2; done` )
```

the `insert` variable is an **array** holding 2 elements

```
sed "s|$|,${insert}|" test
```

`${insert}` only retrieves the **first** element -- it is implicitly `${insert[0]}`

I would rewrite that like this, to read the file line-by-line:

```
while IFS=, read -ra fields; do
    ip=$( python getattrib.py get "${fields[0]}" | cut -d"'" -f2 )
    printf "%s" "$ip"
    printf ",%s" "${fields[@]}"
    echo
done < test
```